# Regarding a use case on queries in Druid

Tags: mysql, sql, real-time, user-defined-functions, druid

I have a use case in druid where real-time data comes in the format like,

```
           task{
               taskno;
               category;
             }
```

Here category can be "assigned" or "unassigned".Suppose tasks with the following came,

```
           taskno:1,category:"assigned"
           taskno:2,category:"unassigned"
           taskno:3,category:"assigned"
           taskno:4,category:"assigned"
```

Here if I perform a query with filter as "category" with count(*) on it ,I will get result as;

```
            assigned:3 
            unassigned:1
```

Now a new event comes with

```
           taskno:2,category:"assigned"
```

I want in such a way that the query results

```
            assigned:4
            unassigned:0
```

Is there any way I can do like this using Javascript UDF or something in druid?
Thanks.

Comment: If the timestamp is same for both the events with "taskno:2" there is a way to override the previous data

Comment: oh, glad to know that @mdeora, but unfortunately timestamp for both are different in my use case :(.Do you know what to do if timestamps are different?

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter your query on task and than filter it on category with order as desc and limit 1. It should give you the desired result.

And in your function where you getting the results you can addup the counts, or you can write a post aggregation function to do the same in druid.